# download one by one using nsurlconnection

Tags: ios, download, queue, nsurlconnection

i want to download multiple files one by one using NSURLconnection and the maximum downloads one can do is 5. the process is like initiate first download ,when the first download is complete then only start the second download and when second is complete start the third one.Likewise for forth download and fifth download.i am able to download a single file .The code for the same is:

```
- (IBAction)download1:(id)sender {
    _fileName = @"dog-wallpaper-dogs.jpg";
    _currentURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://noruffdaysdotcom1.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/%@",_fileName];
    NSLog(@"currenturl%@",_currentURL);

    NSLog(@"the filename is %@",_fileName);

    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:_currentURL];
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];

    _receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]initWithLength:0];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];


}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    NSLog(@"THE STATUS CODE IS %d",[httpResponse statusCode]);
    statuscode = [httpResponse statusCode];
    NSLog(@"into didReceiveResponse");
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    [_receivedData setLength:0];
    expectedBytes = [response expectedContentLength];
    NSLog(@"EXPECTED BYTES:%ld",expectedBytes);
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
   // NSLog(@"into did receivedata");
    [_receivedData appendData:data];
    //   float progressive = (float)[_receivedData length] / (float)expectedBytes;


}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    flag= 0;
    NSLog(@"into didfailwitherror");
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSLog(@"connection failed");
}

-(NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse
{
    return nil;
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{   flag = 0;
    NSLog(@"into didfinishloading");
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"DOCUMENT DIRECTORY :%@",documentsDirectory);
    //   [NSFileManager isWritbleAtPath:documentsDirectory];
    //  [NSFileManager isWritableAtPath:documentsDirectory];
    _imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:_fileName];
    NSLog(@"iamge path:%@",_imagePath);
    NSLog(@"succeeded");
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible= NO;
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[_receivedData length]);

    // flag= [_receivedData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:NO];
    if([_receivedData writeToFile:_imagePath atomically:YES])
    {
        flag= 1;
        NSLog(@"write successfull");

    }
    else{
        flag =0;
        NSLog(@"write failed");
    }
    UIImage *img =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:_imagePath];
    self.imageview.image = img;
    isloaded = YES;
}
```

Please help me how i do next downloads on completion of earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use NSURLConnection in this way:

create an operation queue with maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

```
NSOperationQueue *requestsQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[_requestsQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
```

and start all your connections in this way:

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:@"http://yourUrlRequest.com"];
 .
 . // configure your request
 .

 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                   queue:requestsQueue
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

// handle your request here
}
```

when the request ends the next one start, so adding all your asynch request , them will be started one by one (queue concurrency = 1)

in case one fails and you want to cancel all the requests just suspend the queue and remove all the requests

```
[requestsQueue setSuspended:YES];
[requestsQueue cancelAllOperations];
```